# NPM and YARN not installing packgaes

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

While installing any package 
yarn is giving error

```
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

I visited the https://registry.yarnpkg.com it gave

```
  {"db_name":"registry","doc_count":889991,"doc_del_count":342,"update_seq":11137048,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":13042010533,"data_size":5649135494,"instance_start_time":"1527001930076866","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":11137047}
```

Moreover npm is giving the

```
 Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect 
 ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

using no proxy